# gevent queue how to block and empy queue till item is in queue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent

Gevent is not working.  I would figure the below would block forever yet I get the below error.

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
import gevent.queue    
queue = gevent.queue.Queue()
queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)



File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/zenserver/upload_pusher.py", line 53, in proccess_file
    filepath = queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/queue.py", line 189, in get
    result = waiter.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/hub.py", line 616, in get
    return self.hub.switch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/hub.py", line 373, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that exception because there's no other greenlet to switch to. You've asked the one and only greenlet (the main greenlet) to block, but there's no way it can ever wake up (because there are no other greenlets). Basically this is gevent letting you know about a deadlock.